# Undefined reference to `Function' C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have researched a solution for this error but I still don't get it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calcF(float a, float b, float c); 

int main(void) 
{
float mag_flux_den, cur, len; 
float result;

printf("What is the magnetic flux density in tesla? : ");
scanf("%f", &mag_flux_den);
printf("What is the current in the conductor in Amperes? : ");
scanf("%f", &cur);
printf("What is the length of the conductor in the magnetic field in metres? : ");
scanf("%f", &len);

result = calcF(mag_flux_den, cur, len);

printf("Force on the current carrying conductor: %f", result);
return 0;
}

float calcf(float a, float b, float c) //calculates force on the current carrying conductor{
      float F;
F = a * b * c;
return F;   
}
```

I am using ideone.com and still getting the same error message (`undefined reference to 'calcF'`). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Change your comment from `//` to `/* ... */`, and everything should be fine. Also correct the case: either `calcF` or `calcf` everywhere (prototype declaration, function definition and functiona call).

Comment: `{` is included as part of comment. Move it before the `//`. For inline or multi-line comments use `/* .. */`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your function as "calcF" with a capital "F", but your definition is "calcf" with a lowercase "f". Make sure they are the same.

Also, your function definition at the bottom of your code block has it's open bracket at the end of the comment.

Move it after the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> 

float calcF(float a, float b, float c); 

int main(void) 
{
      float mag_flux_den, cur, len; 
      float result;

      printf("What is the magnetic flux density in tesla? : ");
      scanf("%f", &mag_flux_den);
      printf("What is the current in the conductor in Amperes? : ");
      scanf("%f", &cur);
      printf("What is the length of the conductor in the magnetic field in metres? : ");
      scanf("%f", &len);

      result = calcF(mag_flux_den, cur, len);

      printf("Force on the current carrying conductor: %f", result);
      return 0;
}

float calcF(float a, float b, float c) //calculates force on the current carrying conductor
{
      float F;
      F = a * b * c;
      return F;   
}
```

Comment: Don't just throw some code at OP. Explain what he did wrong!